# Is merging two many to many relation in one relation table better than seperated relations?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have tree table which two of them have a many to many relation with third table. now I want to know if I merge this relations together and create one relation table for this relations is a bad practice or not?
[image: merge two many2many relation together]

I think this design mede my relation and oprations easier to manage and easier understand. but I am worry about performance.
I want to know which one way has better performance?

shared middle table which I add its picture or create a middle table for each relation?

Comment: I'd rather merge `tbl_2` and `tbl_3`.

Comment: they have many different data and field and in my ORM (laravel-Eloquent) there is no support for the inherited model mapping.

Comment: You didn't tag ORM or laravel. However - you would workaround with a hasOne relation (`Movie has-one Media and Book has-one Media` instead of `Movie extends Media and Book extends Media`). Then you can have a single but clean junction table `media_tags` instead of two tables `books_tags` and `movie_tags` or a polymorphic relation.

Comment: A 3-way many:many mapping may or may not be a good idea.  It depends on how many in each direction, how big the tables are, how often you need to use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` when using it for 2-way but getting duplicates, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex junctions aren't bad in and of themselves. A row in a `prescriptions` table could well have `doctor_id`, `patient_id`, and `pharmacy_id` values. This works because a single prescription represents the confluence of doctor, patient, and pharmacy (plus some other information which could be factored out into still more related tables). The important part is that the prescription can only be expressed in terms of several foreign keys.

What you have is different. You're describing a case where a row in `tbl_1` can be linked to `tbl_2` *or* `tbl_3` depending on the value of `rel_type`. Multiple connections are possible with multiple `rel_type`s. *This* is bad, because you can't create an enforceable foreign key constraint on `tbl_x_id`. It may look simpler at first glance because there's only one junction table, but it's hiding a lot of complexity in ways that will hurt later. It'll perform worse, but the real issue is the lack of referential integrity.